# Is Stream.toArray() a thread safe mutable reduction?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream

The collect operation in Java 8 Stream API is defined as a *mutable reduction* that can be safely executed in parallel, even if the resulting `Collection` is not thread safe.

Can we say the same about the `Stream.toArray()` method?

Is this method a mutable reduction that is thread safe even if the `Stream` is a parallel stream and the resulting array is not thread safe?

Comment: *resulting Array is not thread safe* - what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `toArray` operation is a kind of *Mutable Reduction*, though not implemented exactly like the `collect` operation. Instead, it’s more efficient in some cases. But these are unspecified implementation details. The documentation of `toArray` itself does not say anything about how it is implemented, so regarding your question, you have to resort to more general statements:

#### [package documentation, “Parallelism”](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)

> … All streams operations can execute either in serial or in parallel.
>
> …
>
> Except for operations identified as explicitly nondeterministic, such as `findAny()`, whether a stream executes sequentially or in parallel should not change the result of the computation.
>
> …
>
> Most stream operations accept parameters that describe user-specified behavior, which are often lambda expressions. To preserve correct behavior, these *behavioral parameters* must be *non-interfering*, and in most cases must be *stateless*.

So regardless of how it’s implemented, `toArray` is a stream operation that can run in parallel and since it’s not specified to have any restrictions or nondeterministic behavior, it will produce the same (correct) result as in sequential mode. That’s the only thing you have to think about.

But if you use the overloaded method [`toArray(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-), it’s your responsibility to provide an appropriate function, e.g. `SomeType[]::new` is always non-interfering and stateless so the form `toArray(SomeType[]::new)` is also thread safe.

Answer (score 5):

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction- it should be since they create

> ... any additional arrays that might be required for a partitioned execution or for resizing

And in deduction, since `Stream.toArray()` is nothing but `stream.toArray(Object[]::new)` it should hold for `Stream.toArray()` too.